# How to inject Unity Container dependency in ActionFilter Attribute, in Webapi

Tags: c#, frameworks, unity-container, webapi, custom-action-filter

after doing all the configuration in UnityConfig I am not able to see Instant in Action filter.
inject Unity Container dependency in ActionFilter Attribute, is it possible to inject inside ActionFilter.

help me inject Unity inject using Property inject

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.